# Is XPath sum or fn:sum function implemented in PostgreSQL XPath?

Tags: xml, postgresql, sum, xpath

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4 **XPath (XML functions)** feature. This is an adapted example found in docs:

```
SELECT xpath('/my:a/value[.>15]',
'<my:a xmlns:my="http://example.com">
<value>20</value>
<value>10</value>
<value>30</value>
</my:a>',
ARRAY[ARRAY['my', 'http://example.com']]);
```

This works fine, it returns a list of nodes correctly filtered with *"value>15"* condition:

```
xpath  
xml[]  
---------------------------------------  
"{<value>20</value>,<value>30</value>}"
```

But when I try to use **"sum"** it returns an empty list instead of a *scalar value*:

```
SELECT xpath('sum(/my:a/value[.>15])',  
...
```

result:

```
xpath  
xml[]  
-----  
"{}"
```

Any suggestions?

Juan Ferreyra

Comment: PostgreSQL uses whatever is implemented in libxslt.

Comment: About the XPath expression, do note that `sum(/my:a/value[.>15])` should return a numeric scalar value, not a node set.

Comment: There are a generic problem with PostgreSQL, from  v8.4 to v9.1, they not return scalar values from XPath. See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15309880/287948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xpath` does not create new nodes, it only filters the currently existing ones. That's what `XSLT` is for.

From the [**docs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-xml.html):

> The function `xpath` evaluates the XPath expression `xpath` against the XML value `xml`. It returns an array of XML values corresponding to the node set produced by the XPath expression.

Since your XPath expression does not return a node set, there are not values in it and there is nothing to return.

Comment: Right, the xpath function always returns a node set. So I probably need some other function that returns scalar values, but I think it doesn't exists :(
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_1.0#Number_functions

Comment: @Juan: why don't you use `SQL` to build the scalar value out of a set? After all, `SQL` is much better for processing the sets.

Comment: I'm really using org.apache.commons.jxpath library to run (in Java) some more complex xpath formulas, configured in db. I was just trying to use Postgres to evaluate or test the same xpath formulas, that in all cases returns a number. Not big deal.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the same problem and I am pleased to add another answer to the question:

With PostgreSQL 9.2 the documentation suddenly has one more sentence covering the xpath function:

> If the XPath expression returns a scalar value rather than a node set,
>   a single-element array is returned.

Just what I need! So in relation to the question another valid answer is: Upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.2. In the moment of writing this, version 9.2 is just a beta, but I can confirm that this works:

### Version details

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                     version                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2beta1 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

### Demonstration of solution

(This demonstration was made with Postgre 9.5, because originally I pasted the wrong code)

```
postgres=# SELECT xpath('sum(/my:a/value[.>15])', '<my:a xmlns:my="http://example.com">
postgres'# <value>20</value>
postgres'# <value>10</value>
postgres'# <value>30</value>
postgres'# </my:a>',
postgres(# ARRAY[ARRAY['my', 'http://example.com']]);
 xpath 
-------
 {50}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Your demonstration not have a XPath expression that "... returns a scalar value rather than a node set..." . In [this another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15309880/287948) we have a typical `count` returning scalar, can you test with pg9.2?

Comment: Indeed it works! Please @yankee, could you fix your answer?