# XPath1 at SQL/XML, count elements returns empty

Tags: postgresql, xpath, count, sqlxml

I am using [PostgreSQL 9](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-xml.html), that adopts [XPath-1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for the [SQL/XML standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/XML) compliance.

This query is ok, returns the expected data:

```
 SELECT xpath('//img',xhtm) FROM t
```

but this other one, to count img elements, returns empty (!),

```
 SELECT xpath('count(//img)',xhtm) FROM t
```

---

*NOTE* 1: a `xhtm` field content sample,

```
 <html><p>Hello! <img src="1.png"/></p><img src="2.jpg"/></html>
```

*NOTE* 2: of course `array_length(xpath('//img',xhtm),1)` show the count result, but it is not a XPath counting.

*NOTE* 3: I don't know if it is a generic SQL/XML peculiarity, or a *PosgreSQL Server 9.0.5* specific bug/problem.

Comment: Can you show us your XML content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:
As I noted in the comments below, and as indicated in [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10692439/1945651), this issue was apparently addressed in Postgresql 9.2.  That answer states:

> With PostgreSQL 9.2 the documentation suddenly has one more sentence covering the xpath function:
>
> *If the XPath expression returns a scalar value rather than a node set, a single-element array is returned.*
>
> Just what I need! So in relation to the question another valid answer is: Upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.2.

Below is the rest of my original answer:

This seems to be a known limitation in Postgresql's `xpath()` function - only expressions that evaluate to a node-set return anything; XPath expressions that would return a scalar value just return an empty array.

Some Google searches reveal some discussion about this about 2 years ago primarily from a person named Florian Pflug:

http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/PATCH-Bug-in-XPATH-if-expression-returns-a-scalar-value-td4440233.html

He has developed a patch that supposedly fixes the issue and that is attached to the following thread (though I'm not entirely sure this is the latest version):

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/FC60A4F5-5560-438C-97E8-B6D1FDE1CC2B@phlo.org

There does seem to be some discussion about the pros and cons of his patch, so I'd suggest reading through these threads to be aware of what is involved:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201106291957.04251.rsmogura@softperience.eu
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201106291934.23089.rsmogura@softperience.eu

Comment: Hum... Ok, a PostgreSQL BUG... No 2013 solution for the problem??

Comment: After a little more digging [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10692439/1945651) seems to suggest that the limitation was remedied in 9.2 (though the example the poster used doesn't actually verify that, oddly).

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I followed your tip (the SO answer) and requested @yankee to test a scalar case... So, here is Yankee with the test result!  Now I  really believe that pg9.2 is my solution ;-)

Comment: Problem: you (JLRishe) do the "digging work", but Yankee show the solution in the body of the answer... I will vote to both... But the bounty goes to who?  (checking rules and waiting other's votes).

Comment: Well, technically I _did_ provide the answer in the comments and just hadn't added it to the body of my answer yet. I have modified it now. Of course, it's up to you to pick a winner, but if you don't, and nobody votes, neither of us will get the bounty. If there are more votes, then the person with the most votes will get half the bounty.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: I believe that JLRishe put more effort into the question than I did and without him I would not even have been aware of your question. Thus I suggest you give the bounty to JLRishe. However, I believe that accepting an answer is independent from assigning the bounty so if my answer was what was helpful to you in the first place, then accept my answer, while awarding the bounty to JLRishe at the same time ;-).

Answer (score 2):

JLRishe made me aware of your question. I had the same problem in May last year and I discovered that the problem was fixed in PostgreSQL 9.2.

Since version 9.2. the documentation states:

> If the XPath expression returns a scalar value rather than a node set,
>   a single-element array is returned.

I just downloaded PostgreSQL 9.2 and ran your example:

```
postgres=# select version();   
                                                    version                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT xpath('count(//img)','<html><p>Hello! <img src="1.png"/></p><img src="2.jpg"/></html>'::xml);
 xpath 
-------
 {2}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now we have a reliable proof that pg9.2 works (!), and another witness that pg9.1, pg9.0, and pg.8.X have a BUG... Well I need to supplicate my hosting service, to upgrade pg9.1.